# Exporting USGS contour line shapefile to DWG or DXF?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, contour, dwg

How do I assign the Z value based on the Elevation attribute using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop?

I've been messing with this for an hour or two now and every time the exported DWG has ZERO for z value for all lines.

Comment: I've found in some searching that just changing the elevation field to be named "Elevation" (currently it is "ContourEle") will get the exporter to automatically change this. BUT YOU CANT RENAME FIELDS - any ideas?

Comment: can you add a field called Elevation and just set it equal to the values in ContourEle?

Comment: Llaves, thanks for this - duh. this was the easy way.

Comment: Is there any way i can pick up terrain details of an area using Arcgis 9.3.1.
Actually iam looking to make a contour map of an area using gis from images without any filed work,by means the x,y and z values can be pick up from any satellite source or any paid source.
Help me out please?

Comment: Hasan, this is not an answer to this question, please create your own. 
http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 4):

I managed to do this by making a new field in my shapefile called 'ELEVATION'. You can add fields in ArcCatalog. I copied the data over to the new 'ELEVATION' field, so the two were identical. When I exported to CAD, CAD picked up the data seamlessly.

Answer (score 1):

You need the 3D Analyst Extension to do this: [**Feature To 3D By Attribute (3D Analyst)**](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Feature_To_3D_By_Attribute/00q90000002z000000/)

After you've created the 3D features run [**Export to CAD**](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00120000001n000000) to convert the features to DWG/DXF.